# Converting from Array of Arrays to Single Array

Tags: php, arrays, key

How do I make this:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => array(1) {
    ["bleh"] => int(109720)
  }
  [1] => array(1) {
    ["bleh"] => int(112439)
  }
}
```

into this most efficiently?

```
array(2) {
  0 => 109720,
  1 => 112439
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not follow the measurements given in the comments below konforces answer, however this one is minimally faster than a foreach using refs:

```
$c=count($array);
for(
  $i=0;
  $i<$c
  ;
  $array[$i]=$array[$i]['bleh'],
  $i++
);
```

Won't say it's trivial to actually measure it, the timings change a bit depending on which one comes first, this is over an array with ten million members as per the question:

```
foreach ref: 4.192161
foreach key: 4.383342
foreach copy: 4.222771
array_map lambda: 12.240275
array_map reset: 16.401093
for key: 3.459406
for copy: 4.690722
```

Script:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', -1); // wer're going to consume a lot.
$arrayCount = 10000000;

$test = 'just run';
$array = array_fill(0, $arrayCount, array("bleh" => 109720,));
$array = end($array);
$array = array_fill(0, $arrayCount, array("bleh" => 109720,));
$array = array_map(function(){}, $array);

$test = 'foreach ref';
$array = array_fill(0, $arrayCount, array("bleh" => 109720,));
$start = microtime(1);
foreach($array as &$v) $v = $v['bleh'];
unset($v);
$diff = microtime(1)-$start;
$tests[$test] = $diff;
printf("%s: %f\n", $test, $diff);

$test = 'foreach key';
$array = array_fill(0, $arrayCount, array("bleh" => 109720,));
$start = microtime(1);
foreach($array as $k => $v) $array[$k] = $v['bleh'];
$diff = microtime(1)-$start;
$tests[$test] = $diff;

printf("%s: %f\n", $test, $diff);
$test = 'foreach copy';
$array = array_fill(0, $arrayCount, array("bleh" => 109720,));
$start = microtime(1);
foreach($array as $k => $v) $arrayb[] = $v['bleh'];
$diff = microtime(1)-$start;
$tests[$test] = $diff;
unset($arrayb);
printf("%s: %f\n", $test, $diff);

$test = 'array_map lambda';
$array = array_fill(0, $arrayCount, array("bleh" => 109720,));
$start = microtime(1);
$array = array_map(function($e) { return $e['bleh']; }, $array);
$diff = microtime(1)-$start;
$tests[$test] = $diff;
printf("%s: %f\n", $test, $diff);

$test = 'array_map reset';
$array = array_fill(0, $arrayCount, array("bleh" => 109720,));
$start = microtime(1);
$array = array_map('reset', $array);
foreach($array as $k => $v) $arrayb[] = $v['bleh'];
$diff = microtime(1)-$start;
$tests[$test] = $diff;
printf("%s: %f\n", $test, $diff);

$test = 'for key';
$array = array_fill(0, $arrayCount, array("bleh" => 109720,));
$start = microtime(1);
for($i=0,$c=count($array);$i<$c;$array[$i]=$array[$i]['bleh'],++$i);
$diff = microtime(1)-$start;
$tests[$test] = $diff;
printf("%s: %f\n", $test, $diff);

$test = 'for copy';
$array = array_fill(0, $arrayCount, array("bleh" => 109720,));
$start = microtime(1);
for($i=0,$c=count($array);$i<$c;$arrayb[]=$array[$i]['bleh'],++$i);
$diff = microtime(1)-$start;
$tests[$test] = $diff;
unset($arrayb);
printf("%s: %f\n", $test, $diff);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map).

```
$a = array_map(function($e) { return $e['bleh']; }, $a);
```

Comment: Good answer!  Uses lambda expression which will limit it to PHP 5.3 only however.

Comment: Looks great, but not so efficient.

Comment: @danielsmith: w/o lambda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614562/converting-from-array-of-arrays-to-single-array/6614640#6614640

Comment: @Radu, by what benchmark? Perhaps something like `$l = count($a); for ($i=0; $i<$l; ++$i) $a[$i] = $a[$i]['bleh'];` is faster and uses less memory, but is the difference really going to be meaningful? One should generally focus on choosing the proper algorithm (every answer here is essentially the same) and write understandable code, and not worry so much about trivial optimization.

Comment: @konforce, I agree about writing readable code. All the answers are readable (arguably the `foreach` example is the most readable because you can understand what it does the second you look at it, without need for documentation). But as far as execution speed goes, this is twice as slow as the `foreach` example and the `reset` example is twice as slow as this one. If you have many values, you will see the difference.

Comment: @Radu, and how does the `for()` compare? Where do you draw the line at fast enough? I don't really disagree with anything in particular that you are saying... it's just people on SO are quick to both ask and respond about optimization without either actually running any benchmarks or thinking about whether or not it is actually useful.

Comment: @konforce, actually the `for` example is just slightly slower than the `foreach` one (insignificantly slower). I did benchmark, I didn't base my comment just on personal experience. I'm also not advocating premature optimization and I'm not just saying "don't do this because I say it's not good", I'm just bringing an argument. I found out the hard way how much it matters to choose both a fast and easy to read solution. If you routinely use good practices, then you will be in less pain in the long run.

Comment: @Radu, but the `for` loop (as I wrote it) should use half the memory, which is often more important than speed when it comes to PHP... since it's so bad with memory. The most efficient (fastest) solution in this case would probably be to either a) build the array properly from the start or b) just use it in all its multidimensional glory.

Comment: @konforce, you're right, if the `$a` array may be changed, then your `for` example is optimal in every way. It's actually twice as fast as the `foreach` example with a separate array and the memory savings are great too. This more than makes up for the less readable form.

Answer (score 4):

try [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php)

```
  $result = array_map("reset", $a);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need a fast solution (good execution speed) then:

```
$a = /* the original array */;
$b = array();
foreach ($a as $value) {
    $b[] = $value['bleh'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$all = array(
    array( "one"    => 1),
    array( "two"    => 2),
    array( "three"  => 3)
);

function getKey($item)
{
    return key($item);
}

function getVal($item)
{
    return $item[key($item)];
}
$keys   = array_map("getKey", $all);
$values = array_map("getVal", $all);
print_r($keys);
print_r($values);

OUTPUT:

Array (
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three ) 
Array (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3 )
```